# Oracle PL/SQL - Declare constant with constrainst inside procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, constants, constraints, procedure

Is it possible to declare constants with constraints inside a procedure?

Something like:

```sql
declare
procedure proc
   (param1 IN VARCHAR2,
    param2 IN VARCHAR2,
    param3 IN NUMBER)
is
BEGIN
  my_const CONSTANT VARCHAR2(50) := param1  -- Notice the constraint where my_const is VARCHAR2(50)
  other_c  CONSTANT VARCHAR2(50) := 'My other constant!'

  -- Do something with my_const and other_c
END;
```

The idea to have a constraint is that I want to cause an error if someone supplies a value too long.

It's not possible to define a constraint at the parameter.
I can't do this (at least I tried):

```sql
declare
procedure proc
   (param1 IN VARCHAR2(50),
    param2 IN VARCHAR2(50),
    param3 IN NUMBER)
is
BEGIN
  other_c  CONSTANT VARCHAR2(50) := 'My other constant!'

  -- Do something with other_c
END;
```

I know I can just check the length with an `if` and emit an exception if too long, but I'm looking for a simpler way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the parameter directly into the value of a constant, but if it doesn't fit you will get a `VALUE_ERROR`. You will need to catch that error in your exception handling, or remove the exception handling if you want the error to be raised.

```sql
DECLARE
    PROCEDURE proc (param1 IN VARCHAR2, param2 IN VARCHAR2, param3 IN NUMBER)
    IS
        my_const   VARCHAR2 (5) := param1;   -- Notice the constraint where my_const is VARCHAR2(5)
        other_c    VARCHAR2 (5) := 'other';
    BEGIN
        -- Do something with my_const and other_c
        NULL;
    END;
BEGIN
    proc ('long_val', 'test', 0);
EXCEPTION
    WHEN VALUE_ERROR
    THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Something doesn''t fit');
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try sth. like this - inner block of code with declaration of your constant and assignment of the input param; you can also include exception block inside your procedure;
For presentation purposes I added this block to block which is calling your proc.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc (
    param1   IN   VARCHAR2,
    param2   IN   VARCHAR2,
    param3   IN   NUMBER
) IS
BEGIN
  -- Do something with other_c
    DECLARE
        my_const   CONSTANT VARCHAR2(50) := param1;
        other_c    CONSTANT VARCHAR2(50) := 'My other constant!';
    BEGIN
        dbms_output.put_line('other_c'
                             || chr(10)
                             || other_c);
        dbms_output.put_line('my_const'
                             || chr(10)
                             || my_const);
    END;
END;
/
```

and here's an example method call:

```
BEGIN
    proc(param1 => 'sdfasdfsadfsdfadsfasfasdfsadfa32234fdasdfsadfsdfsadfaf', param2 => 'something', param3 => 1);
EXCEPTION
    WHEN value_error THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('Invalid input param!');
END;
/
```